# Use Active Directory App Roles with social accounts

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

Are Azure Active Directory app roles only supported for accounts in the same tenancy?

I am trying to use Azure Active Directory to authenticate users both on my tenancy, others, and social accounts, and be able to manually assign different app-level roles.

#### What I would like:

- Users would sign up using any of these methods, and I would see them in the 'Users and groups' blade of the Enterprise Application in Azure portal (or I could invite them). I would assign app roles (roles specific to my app, eg engineer/technician/residential user) via the 'Add user/group' button.
- When logging in to my app, I retrieve the app roles via `idTokenClaims.roles[]`

#### What happens instead:

- This works fine for user accounts already in my Azure tenancy. But for other Microsoft accounts (eg `theirname@outlook.com` or MS accounts created with any email address), the user doesn't appear in Azure portal after logging in unless I manually invite them. After inviting them (and accepting the invite), I see a user like `theirname_outlook.com#EXT#@mytenancy.onmicrosoft.com`. I can assign app roles to this user, but their `idTokenClaims.roles[]` is not returned.
- Other social accounts (eg Twitter, facebook) seem to not be supported at all

#### What else I tried

I also investigated AD B2C, which gives the developer more control over the login flow, and supports other social accounts other than MS (which looks good), but it seems that doesn't support app roles at all.

Am I trying to use the wrong tool for the job?
All I want to do is support any user to sign up to my app, and for an admin to set what their app-specific roles should be.

#### Update

I am using the MSAL auth library, following the [instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-nodejs-webapp-msal#add-app-registration-details)

> `https://login.microsoftonline.com/Enter_the_Tenant_Id_here` should be one of the following:
>
> - If your application supports accounts in this organizational directory, replace this value with the Tenant ID or Tenant name. For example, contoso.microsoft.com.
> - If your application supports accounts in any organizational directory, replace this value with organizations.
> - If your application supports accounts in any organizational directory and personal Microsoft accounts, replace this value with `common`.
> - To restrict support to personal Microsoft accounts only, replace this value with `consumers`.

Because I wanted this to work with any social account, I chose `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common`. This shows a UI that allows you to use any organisation or personal MS account, or sign up for a personal MS account with any email address. But I noticed the `objectId` returned for personal accounts is *different* to the id when I manually invite the account in azure portal. I changed to use my `TenantID` instead, and that worked. Personal accounts that have been previously invited via portal can log in. Other personal accounts get an error and cant log in. App roles are now returned for these personal accounts. This now partially solves my original problem, but I still have some unsolved issues:

- this method shows a slightly different UI that doesn't allow the user to sign up for a new MS account in this flow
- I still can't use other oauth accounts eg Twitter/Facebook. Do these not support app roles at all?
- the instructions quoted above seem incorrect, clearly it is possible to log in using "accounts in any organizational directory and personal Microsoft accounts" via `TenentID`, not `common`, once they've been invited to the app

Comment: `appRole` certainly supports social accounts, you only need to parse the **access token** and then view the `roles` claim.

Comment: Is there an update?

Answer (score 0):

App roles absolutely support guest accounts. But as you can see, the id token of the guest account does not seem to contain the `roles` claim, and it is not clear whether this is by design. But the `roles` claim will appear in the access token.

I think an access token you can be used, and the access token also contains user information.

[image]

Comment: What authority did you use here to get the token? `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common` or `/TenantId`?
See my update

Comment: @rockgecko  I use `/TenantId`, because I need to add a personal account to Azure ad to grant app role to the account.